# How to display block from left to right in css

Tags: html, css

My problem is that i want to display block from left to right. You can see my current effect and red box what I'm expecting to get.

what I'm doing wrong? as i did tried to use float left on nmenu_drop class.

[image]

CSS:

```
.wraper{
    margin-left:10px;
    float:left;
    position:relative;

}
.notification_dropdown{
    height:40px;
    margin-right:10px;
    float: right;
    position:relative; 
    padding-left: 10px;
    width:30px;
}

.nmenu_drop{
    width:200px;
    height:300px;
    background:#FFF; 
    clear:both;
    position:absolute; 
    margin-top:40px;
    float:right;
}

.nmenu_drop{
    display: none;
}
.notification_dropdown:hover + .nmenu_drop {
    display: block;
    background:#4B4B4B;
}

.nmenu_drop:hover {
    display: block;
}
.notification_dropdown:hover{
    background:#4B4B4B;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="wraper">
   <div class="notification_dropdown">
        <i class="fa fa-globe" style="font-size: 21;color: #8a8a8a; margin-top: 9px;"></i>
   </div>

   <div class="nmenu_drop">
        notification
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding:

```
.nmenu_drop {
    right: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It was simple and helpful solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can play with left and transition:

```
#wrapper{
    position: relative; /* Important, we are going to offset to this div*/
}
#menu{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%; /* It looks mobile, so I took this */
    top: 0;
    left: -105%; /* The extra 5% is easy fix to paddings and borders and stuff */
    transition: left 0.5s; /* animate it */
}
#menu.Opened{
    left: 0; /* position moved back in */
}
```

All you have to do now is to add a class `Opened` to it.
  [I've made a small demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZsEGG/2/)